# How to know that selected element is input field or not?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I need to know whether the selected element is input field or not.

As we know that input field in HTML is many. like input element, a div with content editable `attr`, textfield, etc., and i need to know whether my selected element is editable or not. some thing like this.

```
$(document).click(function(e){
        if($(e.target).is('[contenteditable="true"]')){
            alert("i am edit able");
        }
    });
```

in this it can able to say element is editable only if `contenteditable="true"` is present. So is there any common `attr` or property for editable file. if so answer, if not list out all possible editable text/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you can use :input selector

```js
$(document).click(function(e) {
  if ($(e.target).is('[contenteditable], :input:not(:button)')) {
    snippet.log("i am editable: " + e.target.tagName);
    console.log(this)
  }
});
```

```css
div {
  border: 1px solid lightgrey;
}
```

```html
<!-- Provides the `snippet` object, see http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/242144/134069 -->
<script src="http://tjcrowder.github.io/simple-snippets-console/snippet.js"></script>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div contenteditable></div>
<input />
<textarea></textarea>
<select></select>
<div>some other content</div>
<button>Button</button>
<input type="button" value="T Button" />
<input type="reset" value="T Reset" />
<input type="submit" value="T Submit" />
```

Comment: In fact, `:input` would select non editable elements as `select` or `button`

Comment: So these are all the input elements. None other right? @Arun

Comment: @Vicky https://api.jquery.com/input-selector/ - do you want to select `select` elemetn also

Comment: @A.Wolff we need to exclude `:button`

Comment: @ArunPJohny Ya but looks like the question wasn't clear enough imho :)  `list out all possible editable text`?!